# Shutting down a netty TcpClient channel in Reactor 3.0.4

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I just upgraded projectreactor.io from reactor **OLD**: [core: **3.0.1**.RELEASE, netty: **0.5.2**.RELEASE] to reactor **NEW** [core: **3.0.4**.RELEASE, netty: **0.6.0**.RELEASE].

I open a TcpClient connection and want to close it later.

In the **OLD** version I used

```
tcpClient.shutdown();
```

to disconnect my client from the server.

**Is there an equivalent call in the NEW version? I could not find one!**

I tried the following on both the `NettyInbound` and `NettyOutbound` that I get while creating my TcpClient with `tcpClient.newHandler(...)`

- `.context().dispose()`
- `.context().channel().disconnect()`
- `.context().channel().close()`
- `TcpResources.reset()`

None of them seem to do the job correctly.

I noticed that the respective `.context().onClose(...)`-callback is being called.
But after some additional waiting the server-side checks the connections.
Server-side is plain NIO2 not reactor/netty and while the client was upgraded, the server-side remained unchanged.

With the **OLD** client I got `.isOpen()  == false` for every channel on server-side.

With the **NEW** client I get `.isOpen()  == true` for every channel on server-side. Most of the time I can even write to the channel. And some channels switch to `.isOpen()  == false` after writing few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This deserves an issue I think especially if channel().close() and reset() didn't work. 
Otherwise it might be due to the default pooling and `TcpClient.create(opts -> opts.disablePool())` might help, let us know and if you have a chance to post an issue on http://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty you would be a hero :D

Comment: Also turn on logging (via Slf4j) on info then debug for reactor.ipc.netty. It should show a very verbose track of events after each of your calls.

Comment: opts.disablePool() didn't help. I will try to put together a minimal example for reproduction and file it on github.

Answer (score 0):

Linked to this open issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/15. We will review the dispose API.

Comment: After a long weekend I found some time to put together some test-code and put it with the issue on https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

The following code somehow destroys the channel but not completely.

```
ChannelFuture f = nettyContext.channel().close();
f.sync();

nettyContext.dispose();
```

The problem is that the channel still seems to be open on server-side.
For a NIO2-based server, the server should not test if the channel isOpen(). It's always true.

As a dirty workaround, the server must write to the channel **twice**. If it catches an ExecutionException on the second write then the channel was already closed by the Netty-TcpClient.

```
try {
    channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("hello".getBytes())).get();
    // No exception on first write but on second write.
    channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("bye".getBytes())).get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "ExecutionException on writing from server into channel", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With reactor-core: 3.1.0.M3 and reactor-netty: 0.7.0.M1 the client-API was improved and works more reliable.
After `blockingNettyContext.shutdown()` I still need the following workaround on server-side to make sure the channel was closed:
I need to write into the channel and close it on exception:

```
// channel.isOpen == true
try {
    channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("__test__".getBytes())).get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    channel.close();
}
// channel.isOpen == false
```